# Why JBoss's jsf implementation doesnt have javax.faces.model.DataModel?

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x

I'm trying to migrate an app to JBoss 7.1.1 Final. I was using mojarra 2.0.2 version, as can be seen in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Using JBoss 7.1.1 Final jsf embedded version (jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2), the AS show this Exception:

```
 09:21:16,456 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Projeto316Aplicacao.ear"."Projeto316Apresentacao-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Projeto316Aplicacao.ear"."Projeto316Apresentacao-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Projeto316Apresentacao-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "Projeto316Aplicacao.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/DataModel
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JsfManagedBeanProcessor.java:108)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.model.DataModel from [Module "deployment.Projeto316Aplicacao.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
... 11 more
```

Someone, please, knows why this occours and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Look like a bug in JBoss classloading: https://community.jboss.org/thread/177061 If you provide JSF API/impl in EAR/lib (which is actually the wrong place), then it's solved.

Comment: If you open the "jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar" file, you can see that  the package 'javax.faecs.model.*' does not exists inside it. Do you know why? I will try this lib approach...

Comment: The `javax.faces.*` classes are the API, not the impl. The impl is in case of Mojarra `com.sun.faces.*`. You should look in the API JAR, not the impl JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/DataModel exception in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final is exactly what @BalusC said before:

> Look like a bug in JBoss classloading:
>   community.jboss.org/thread/177061 If you provide JSF API/impl in
>   EAR/lib (which is actually the wrong place), then it's solved. –
>   BalusC Jan 24 at 12:09

If you are using maven, just put

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
....
<defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
```

An another solution (It is not a good practice) is replace the jar in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\sun\jsf-impl\main to another implementation of jsf specification.